# Providing concrete class instance to generic method accepting T, where T extends concrete class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `ShapeDescriber` that looks like this:

```
public class ShapeDescriber<T extends Shape> {
    public void describe(T shape) {
        System.out.println("Its color is " + shape.getColor());
    }
}
```

I use `T` so that subclasses can do something like:

```
public class CircleDescriber<T extends Circle> extends ShapeDescriber<T> {
    public void describe(T circle) {
        super.describe(circle);
        System.out.println("Its radius is " + circle.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I want this `Describer` type hierarchy to match the type hierarchy of my model.

The problem that I run into, is that inside the `CircleDescriber`, I can't pass a `Circle` to my `describe()` method! When I try this:

```
public class CircleDescriber ... {
    ...
    public void printATest() {
        Circle c = new Circle(Colors.GREEN, 10);
        this.describe(c);
    }
}
```

There's a compilation error on my `describe()` call, because:

```
The method describe(T) in the type CircleDescriber<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Circle)
```

Wait. *What?* I feel like this class *knows* that every instance of a `T` will be a subclass of `Circle`, no?

**Edit:** I have created a Gist here for easy copypasting: https://gist.github.com/craigotis/135f88b1ce8beca07400

Note the above Gist will fail to compile.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: How about removing generics and using `Shape` or `Circle` as types? No cast needed as long as the argument extends the specific type of shape.

Comment: @AlexR That won't work, because then the `CircleDescriber` cannot `@Override` the `describe()` method from the `ShapeDescriber` superclass, as the method signature is different.

Comment: @CraigOtis Ah I see. Then you need to test from outside the class instantiating a `CircleDescriber<Circle>` to do the work, since a `Circle` will not suit all `CircleDescriber<T>` (think of a `TexturedCircle` custom class, you wont be allowed to call `describe(Circle)` on a `CircleDescriber<TexturedCircle>`.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks - I have added a Gist: https://gist.github.com/craigotis/135f88b1ce8beca07400

Comment: @CraigOtis: Please re-read the "minimal" part of the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) specification. Your mcve should be small enough to post here with your question, not in a githup link.

Comment: Does your `Circle` extend `Shape`? If not it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work as is, but depending a bit on how you instantiate the `CircleDescriber`. This should work:

```
new CircleDescriber<Circle>().describe(circle);
```

The reason that this does not compile is that you have the test method inside the `CircleDescriber`, with a call to `this`. Since the compiler does not know the generic parameter of `this`, it can't say for sure that passing a `Circle` to it will work (what if `this` refers to a `CircleDescriber` parameterized to a subclass of `Circle`?) Change `this` with `new CircleDescriber<Circle>()` in your test-method, and it shold compile.

But, here you see that you are actually specifying that you are describing a `Circle` twice, both in the class name and in the generic parameter. This should not be necessary, at least as long as `Circle` is a leaf node in your hierarchy. Instead, do this:

(Keep `ShapeDescriber` as is)

```
public class CircleDescriber extends ShapeDescriber<Circle> {
    @Override
    public void describe(Circle circle) {
        super.describe(circle);
        System.out.println("Its radius is " + circle.getRadius());
    }
}
```

Comment: Right - but the problem is that my hierarchy is a bit more complex than in my example. What if I want `ShapeDescriber -> CircleDescriber -> SphereDescriber`? Is there any way to continue allowing the generics to be "passed" down the tree?

Comment: @CraigOtis: `"but the problem is that my hierarchy is a bit more complex than in my example..."` -- which is why you need to create and post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem for us.

Comment: If `Circle` is not a leaf node in the hierarchy, your `CircleDescriber` code should be correct. The problem is how the `CircleDescriber`-object is created (which you are not showing). As long as it is initiated as in the example in the answer above, it should work (from what I can see, haven't actually tried it..)

Comment: Thanks - I have created a Gist and added it to my question: https://gist.github.com/craigotis/135f88b1ce8beca07400 I suppose I'm not really looking to allow callers to parameterize the describer objects - rather, I'm just trying to ensure that my `CircleDescriber` can access `T` as a `Circle` without needing a cast.

Comment: Well, the way you are testing it is incorrect. You can't use `this` for this purpose, since it's a generic class. I would recommend creating a unit-test (`CircleDescriberTest`), with a test-method that contains `new CircleDescriber<Circle>().describe(new Circle());`

Comment: Right - *that* test would work, but ultimately I'd like to be able to call this method from within `CircleDescriber`, and pass it a `Circle`. If I have to remove or alter the generics, no problem - I was just looking for a way to effectively/strictly map my `Describer` model to my object model, minimizing the number of times I need to cast to a specific model type. I like the behavior of `CircleDescriber extends ShapeDescriber<Circle>`, but this prevents me from passing the generic "option" to another subclass.

Comment: With the way it's set up now, you can't call the method with a circle as a parameter from the class itself through `this`. See answer for explanation. I also really can't see why you would want to change your generics setup (which is just fine) in order to get a test to work. IMO production code should never be altered just to make a test pretty. I don't know why you see it necessary to test if  generics, a feature of Java, works the way it should. In addition, your test case is incorrect, since not all instances of `CircleDesciber` will accept a `Circle` as a parameter to the describe-method.

Comment: I'm not trying to test anything, nor alter my generics setup to get a test to work. I see the naming of the `testTheThing()` method was confusing. I'm just trying to, within an existing `CircleDescriber` instance, create a new `Circle` and pass it to the `describe()` method.

Comment: That sounds dangerous. If you `Circle` had a subclass `PerfectCircle`, and you made a `new CircleDescriber<PerfectCircle>()`, then calling the method on it would fail, even if it did compile (you can make it compile by making an unchecked case of `this` to `CircleDescriber<Circle>`, but I really can't recommed it, as it will give a runtime-exception in cases where the `CircleDescriber` in question is parameterized with a subclass of `Circle`.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring :

```
public class CircleDescriber<T extends Circle> extends ShapeDescriber<T>
```

Means that

```
CircleDescriber.describe()
```

gets some class extending `Circle`. For example:

Having a class: `public class RedCircle extends Circle`, you can declare:

`CircleDescriber describer = CircleDescriber<RedCircle>` meaning that `describer` can get `RedCircle` only (and **not** `Circle`). That's why it is not allowed.

Changing to:

```
public class CircleDescriber extends ShapeDescriber<Circle>
```

Would work if you can use `Circle` only.